# What is the unit speed version of this curve?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, plane-curves

I'm trying to find the unit speed version of the curve
$\gamma = (t, 0 , t^2)$. So far I have that $|\gamma^{\prime}|=(\sqrt{1+4t^2})$. I am not sure where to go from here though. My idea was to replace $t$ in $\gamma$ by $\frac{2}{(\sqrt{1+4t^2})}$, but since $|\gamma^{\prime}|$ didn't yield a constant, I'm not sure if this is the right way to go about this. I considered parameterization by arclength, but this doesn't seem like the right manner to go about this either.

Comment: You have to integrate and find the inverse function. However, in practice, you never need to reparametrize explicitly. Just use Frenet with the chain rule. See the second section of my diff geo text, freely linked in my profile.

Comment: I've been trying to find a copy of this text! Thanks, this helps a lot!